# How can I remove border circle in TabPageSelector?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create something like this
[image: 1]]
But when I try to use such code:

```
TabPageSelector(
  controller: _tabController,
  color: Color(0x21000000),
  selectedColor: Colors.white,
),
```

I get in result:
[image]

What I can change for getting the exact result, which I showed in the first picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported by the `TabPageSelector` widget, but you can create your own Widget, I create one for you, check the code and add the file to your project:

https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/9de80d0e22cac8a2ef4357a620b375a9

Usage:

```
        MyTabPageSelector(
                    controller: _controller,
                    color: Color(0x21000000),
                    //borderColor: Colors.blue     you can set your own color if you want
                    selectedColor: Colors.white,
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have understand what you want; to do this , actually ctrl and click on TabPageSelector ,then go to bottom search for TabPageSelectorIndicator (it's in the bottom) , then replace it with what's below with this :

```
class TabPageSelectorIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates an indicator used by [TabPageSelector].
  ///
  /// The [backgroundColor], [borderColor], and [size] parameters must not be null.
  const TabPageSelectorIndicator({
    Key key,
    @required this.backgroundColor,
    @required this.size,
  }) : assert(backgroundColor != null),
       assert(size != null),
       super(key: key);

  /// The indicator circle's background color.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// The indicator circle's diameter.
  final double size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Displays a row of small circular indicators, one per tab. The selected
/// tab's indicator is highlighted. Often used in conjunction with a [TabBarView].
///
/// If a [TabController] is not provided, then there must be a [DefaultTabController]
/// ancestor.
class TabPageSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a compact widget that indicates which tab has been selected.
  const TabPageSelector({
    Key key,
    this.controller,
    this.indicatorSize = 12.0,
    this.color,
    this.selectedColor,
  }) : assert(indicatorSize != null && indicatorSize > 0.0),
       super(key: key);

  /// This widget's selection and animation state.
  ///
  /// If [TabController] is not provided, then the value of [DefaultTabController.of]
  /// will be used.
  final TabController controller;

  /// The indicator circle's diameter (the default value is 12.0).
  final double indicatorSize;

  /// The indicator circle's fill color for unselected pages.
  ///
  /// If this parameter is null then the indicator is filled with [Colors.transparent].
  final Color color;

  /// The indicator circle's fill color for selected pages and border color
  /// for all indicator circles.
  ///
  /// If this parameter is null then the indicator is filled with the theme's
  /// accent color, [ThemeData.accentColor].
  final Color selectedColor;

  Widget _buildTabIndicator(
    int tabIndex,
    TabController tabController,
    ColorTween selectedColorTween,
    ColorTween previousColorTween,
  ) {
    Color background;
    if (tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      // The selection's animation is animating from previousValue to value.
      final double t = 1.0 - _indexChangeProgress(tabController);
      if (tabController.index == tabIndex)
        background = selectedColorTween.lerp(t);
      else if (tabController.previousIndex == tabIndex)
        background = previousColorTween.lerp(t);
      else
        background = selectedColorTween.begin;
    } else {
      // The selection's offset reflects how far the TabBarView has / been dragged
      // to the previous page (-1.0 to 0.0) or the next page (0.0 to 1.0).
      final double offset = tabController.offset;
      if (tabController.index == tabIndex) {
        background = selectedColorTween.lerp(1.0 - offset.abs());
      } else if (tabController.index == tabIndex - 1 && offset > 0.0) {
        background = selectedColorTween.lerp(offset);
      } else if (tabController.index == tabIndex + 1 && offset < 0.0) {
        background = selectedColorTween.lerp(-offset);
      } else {
        background = selectedColorTween.begin;
      }
    }
    return TabPageSelectorIndicator(
      backgroundColor: background,
      size: indicatorSize,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color fixColor = color ?? Colors.transparent;
    final Color fixSelectedColor = selectedColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor;
    final ColorTween selectedColorTween = ColorTween(begin: fixColor, end: fixSelectedColor);
    final ColorTween previousColorTween = ColorTween(begin: fixSelectedColor, end: fixColor);
    final TabController tabController = controller ?? DefaultTabController.of(context);
    assert(() {
      if (tabController == null) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'No TabController for $runtimeType.\n'
          'When creating a $runtimeType, you must either provide an explicit TabController '
          'using the "controller" property, or you must ensure that there is a '
          'DefaultTabController above the $runtimeType.\n'
          'In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.'
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    final Animation<double> animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: tabController.animation,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Semantics(
          label: 'Page ${tabController.index + 1} of ${tabController.length}',
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(tabController.length, (int tabIndex) {
              return _buildTabIndicator(tabIndex, tabController, selectedColorTween, previousColorTween);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the borderStyle

```
 TabPageSelector(
     controller: _tabController,
     color: Color(0x21000000),
     selectedColor: Colors.white,
     borderStyle: BorderStyle.none,
),
```